# How to take an array inside a data frame and turn it into a data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have the following data frame

```
|tokenCnt|filtered                            |
|5       |[java,scala, list, java, linkedlist]|
|3       |[also, genseq, parseq]              |
```

I want to take out the arrays in the column 'filtered' one by one and turn them into one data frame.

```
|filtered|
|java    | 
|scala   | 
|list    |
|java    | 
|linkedList|
|alse      |
|gensqe    |
|parseq    |
```

like this.
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explode`:

```
val result = df.select(explode("filtered").alias("filtered"))
```